# Bootstrap t-test and associated barplots

Tags: t-test, bootstrap

I am trying to figure out the code that will run a bootstrap t-test on multivariate data.  I have two treatments in this experiment (control and trmt).  The response variable is plant cover (there are 26 species of plant).  The sample sizes are unfortunately small so the data is not normally distributed.  What I am trying to do is develop code that will run a bootstrap t-test on each species (control vs trmt), give me an associated test statistic and p=value) and then from that, generate a series of paired barplots for visual comparison.  I've been trying to find code online but to no avail.  My data file (data.frame?) is set up in the typical way to undertake multivariate analysis.  I have a column "trmt" which contains either Control or Treatment and a series of columns corresponding to each plant species with subsequent cells indicating the cover estimate of that species for the quadrat it was found in.
Treatmant Sps1 Sps2 Sps3 Sps4...Sps26
Control   10   5    0    1       2
Trmt      5    1    2    0       7  etc
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks